# Python Addition Program Error - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

I made a simple program where it asks for the user to type in 2 numbers, and the program will add the numbers. For some reason my program gives me an error and I am not sure why. The code is below.

```
choice = input("Enter Choice")
choice2 = input("Enter Choice")

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

if choice == '1':
   print(num1"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
```

The error states Syntax Error - Invalid Syntax.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest finding an capable IDE that will highlight such syntax errors as you type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss a ","

```py
choice = input("Enter Choice")
choice2 = input("Enter Choice")

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

if choice == '1':
   print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1,num2))
```

Answer (score 0):

'add' is not defined. Try below:

> choice = input("Enter Choice") choice2 = input("Enter Choice")
>
> num1 = int(input("Enter first number: ")) num2 = int(input("Enter
>   second number: "))
>
> if choice == '1':    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", num1+num2)